# Retrieve information from CArchive File

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, carchive

Is there any way to retrieve information from a `CArchive` file if we don't know what type of objects are stored in the `CArchive` file?

I want to know in what format information is stored in a `CArchive` file.

Please help me out in this.

Comment: The `CArchive` class has an underlying file object, and that file is (generally) in binary format. So, unless you know *something* about it's contents, it's just gobbledegook.

Comment: I would open that file in a binary editor and see if you can recognize any strings in it. If that archive was created with MFC's serializable CObject-derived things, you may see the class names. If you are lucky

Comment: One Carchive file has given to me. I don't anything what type of information it contains. There is no way to retrieve information from that Carchive file?

Answer (score 5):

The file format is documented under [TN002: Persistent Object Data Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn002-persistent-object-data-format). While that explains how objects are identified in the data stream for deserialization, the actual logic to dump data into the `CArchive` and to read it back is at the discretion of the `CObject`-derived class implementation for classes that use the `DECLARE_SERIAL` and `IMPLEMENT_SERIAL` macros.

Without the actual (de-)serialization code there's little you can do with a binary `CArchive` stream, unless the implementation that produced it uses the standard serialization methods throughout, allowing you to guess the data types stored.

Unlike JSON or XML, though, a `CArchive`'s serialized data isn't self-describing. Even when you know the type of any given piece of data, there's nothing in the file that carries any semantic information.